# Is there any other way to replace Haar cascade in open cv using android

Tags: opencv

I want to know is there any way to replace haar cascade in open cv using android .
If possible please suggest me the way to replace.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add more detail to this question before anyone can hope of answering it properly.

You don't even say what you are trying to detect, or why you cant use the haar cascades?

If you are trying to detect something that does not vary much from image to image (like a logo) then [***here***](http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.org/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_feature2d/py_matcher/py_matcher.html#matcher) is a link to a great resource on how to implement SIFT object detection which *may* fulfill your requirements.

However if you are looking to do face detection (which is what most Haar-Cascades are built for) then using a cascade is definitely the most successful and easiest way to do it.

However you may want to look into implementing a [***Neural Network***](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aQqwGGUppkk) in android that can learn objects (perhaps faces) however the success rate of this network will heavily rely on you managing to train it well.

Please add more to your question so that other people can give you better answers.